# Python pytest does not show assertion differences

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, assert

The following test:

```
def test_something():
    assert "ddd" == "pepe"
```

When run with pytest gives this error message:

```
E       AssertionError: assert 'ddd' == 'pepe'
E         - ddd
E         + pepe
```

However if we move the assert method to a different file `assertion.py`:

```
class CustomerAssertor(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name =name

    def assert_name(self,expected):
        assert self.name ==expected
```

And we change the test to:

```
from sql_gen.test.utils.assertion_util import CustomerAssertor

def test_something():
    CustomerAssertor("ddd").assert_name("pepe")
```

Now I get the following error:

```
self = <assertions.CustomerAssertor object at 0x7fbcc3d31588>, expected = 'pepe'

    def assert_name(self,expected):
>       assert self.name ==expected
E       AssertionError
```

This message is not as informative as it doesn't tell you what the name's value is, why?

Answer (score 17):

From the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#advanced-assertion-introspection):

> Reporting details about a failing assertion is achieved by rewriting assert statements before they are run. Rewritten assert statements put introspection information into the assertion failure message. `pytest` only rewrites test modules directly discovered by its test collection process, so **asserts in supporting modules which are not themselves test modules will not be rewritten**.
>
> You can manually enable assertion rewriting for an imported module by calling [register_assert_rewrite](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#assertion-rewriting) before you import it (a good place to do that is in `conftest.py`).

Comment: Should the call to `register_assert_rewrite` be in conftest.py's global scope or is there a special function where setup should be performed?

Comment: @DanielWalker: I think you just put it in global scope.